# Setting "Discussion" attribute of RTC Work Item

Tags: java, rtc, jazz

I am trying to set the value of "Discussion" at work item pragmatically.

I managed to set the "Description" attribute but when I tried to set the Discussion I got null pointer exception :

```
  IWorkItemClient workItemClient= (IWorkItemClient)repository.getClientLibrary(IWorkItemClient.class);
 IWorkItemWorkingCopyManager manager= workItemClient.getWorkItemWorkingCopyManager();
 manager.connect(workItem, IWorkItem.SMALL_PROFILE, SysoutProgressMonitor.getMonitor());
 WorkItemWorkingCopy wc= manager.getWorkingCopy(workItem);

  IProgressMonitor monitor = SysoutProgressMonitor.getMonitor();
  IWorkItemClient service = (IWorkItemClient) repository.getClientLibrary(IWorkItemClient.class);

   IAttribute discussionAttribute = service.findAttribute(projectArea, "discussion", monitor);//Here I got  a null "discussionAttribute"?

   wc.getWorkItem().setValue(discussionAttribute, "New Value for Discussion");
```

Any ideas!

Comment: What is `null`? the `wc.getWorkItem()`?

Comment: IAttribute discussionAttribute = service.findAttribute(projectArea, "discussion", monitor);//Here I got  a null "discussionAttribute"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `//Here I got a null "discussionAttribute"?`
>   `Attribute discussionAttribute = service.findAttribute(projectArea, "discussion", monitor);`

I suspect "`discussion`" isn't a valid WorkItem attribute id.

Try the question "[Where can I find a list of `IWorkItem` attributes](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/57180/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-iworkitem-attributes)" to query all the attributes of the work item, in order to get the correct attribute name for "`discussion`" (maybe "`comments`"?)

> Use `IItemManager.fetchCompleteItem` to fetch the item for any handle.
>   The items carry the actual info; the handles are essentially just like pointers / URLs.
>
> For example:

```
IContributorHandle contributorHandle = ...

IContributor contributor = (IContributor) teamRepository.itemManager.fetchCompleteItem(contributorHandle, IItemManager.DEFAULT, null);  // should really provide a progress monitor in last arg for progress / cancelaton

String name = contributor.getName();
```

> That's for client-side. For server-side, use IRepositoryItemService to fetch the item.

---

In the attributes of the project area configuration, I see

"Comments": ID "com.ibm.team.workitem.attribute.comments", but no "discussion".

On [Jazz.net](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/112705/setting-discussion-attribute-of-work-item), you find a link to [this discussion](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/94776/assertionfailedexception-problem-with-getting-the-values-of-attributes) and mentions an id named "**`internalComments`**".

Try then:

```
Attribute discussionAttribute = 
  service.findAttribute(projectArea, "internalComments", monitor);
```

---

Don't forget to save your modified Work Item though, as in "[Modify a WorkItem](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/53056/modify-a-workitem)"

```
IDetailedStatus s = wc.save(null);
if (!s.isOK()) {
    throw new TeamRepositoryException("Error saving work item",
                                      s.getException());
}
```

Comment: I tried to fetch the comments by this way but I received a null object:!

IAttribute attribute = service.findAttribute(projectArea, "comments", monitor);

Comment: I found this at my config:
How can I set it programatically! 

<section id="com.ibm.team.workitem.web.inline.section.discussion">
           <presentation id="com.ibm.team.workitem.presentation.discussion" kind="com.ibm.team.workitem.kind.internal.discussion">
               <property key="hideIfCreation" value="true"/>
           </presentation>
       </section>

Comment: @Echo "discussion" is the name of the **GUI widget** which contains comments on the Work Items. However, the attribute (i.e. the *data* attached to a WI, and not its graphical representation) is called ***comments***. See my edited answer.

Comment: I tried the following but I still get null !
Attribute commentAttribute= 
  service.findAttribute(projectArea, "com.ibm.team.workitem.attribute.comments", monitor);

Comment: @Echo true. Let's monitor https://jazz.net/forum/questions/112705/setting-discussion-attribute-of-work-item

Comment: @Echo I have updated the answer with the id `internalComments`.

Comment: I'm trying now to add a comment to it!

Comment: When I tried to set the new comment,everything goes right
However,when I open my work item to find the updates,nothing is added!
Any ideas !!

IComments comments=workItem.getWorkItem().getComments();
IAttribute commentsAttr = service.findAttribute(projectArea, “internalComments”, monitor);
List commentList=new ArrayList();
commentList.add(comments.getContents()[0]);//POC commentList.add(comments.getContents()[0]);
workItem.getWorkItem().setValue(commentsAttr, commentList);

Comment: @Echo yes: you have added a comment, but didn't save the Work Item: `IDetailedStatus s = wc.save(null);`, as in https://jazz.net/forum/questions/53056/modify-a-workitem

Comment: I already had this line ... but I think the issue in that line:
wc.getWorkItem().setValue(commentsAttr, commentList);

For some reason when I removed it ,it works :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the final resolution and it works :)
Thanks to VonC & Sam.

```
IWorkItemClient workItemClient= (IWorkItemClient)repository.getClientLibrary(IWorkItemClient.class);
         IWorkItemWorkingCopyManager manager= workItemClient.getWorkItemWorkingCopyManager();
         manager.connect(workItem, IWorkItem.SMALL_PROFILE, SysoutProgressMonitor.getMonitor());
         WorkItemWorkingCopy wc= manager.getWorkingCopy(workItem);

         IAttribute commentsAttr =  findAttribute(repository, projectArea, "internalComments");
         IComments comments= wc.getWorkItem().getComments();
         IComment comment= comments.createComment( repository.loggedInContributor(),
                 XMLString.createFromPlainText( "Aloo from Mars"));                 

            comments.append(comment); 

            wc.save(null);
```

Comment: Thanks VonC for your assistance  :)